# margin 0 auto; not working

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I am attempting to have several sections auto center using margin: 0 auto, but it will not work. I have looked all over the site. My widths are set, I do not use a float and attempt to use margin, I'm adding the margin to the correct element. But the sections still aren't centering. Any assistance would be very helpful... Thank you in advance.... The CSS code is below...

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
section.Hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
section.Features {
  width: 940px;
  height: 450px;
  background: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section.Organize {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
section.Share {
  width: 940px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section.Get {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<header class="Header">Header</header>

<section class="Hero">Hero</section>

<section class="Features">Features</section>

<section class="Organize">Organize</section>

<section class="Share">Share</section>

<section class="Get">Get</section>

<footer class="Footer">Footer</footer>
```

Comment: where is your html? and it will be much easier to help if you provide a working example (like snippet or jsfiddle)

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=0fnig077zD

Comment: your code seems to work as is .

Comment: According to your snippet everything works just as expected...

Comment: I agree with the others...this works fine!

Comment: I've tried it in Chrome and in FireFDev but 'feature' and 'share' sections are not centering.   It centered in you views?

Comment: Are you looking for your text to be centered? Also, why do you use fixed pixel widths for all elements, but the ones you want "centered" as they are  assigned a width of 100%?

Comment: The sections "Features and Share"  are what I am trying to center.

Comment: I assigned them '940' for the visual effect when centering. But it's not working in my views... I guess back to the drawing board... Thank All.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pwoody/vwnLeng2/ They are definitely centered.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ Reference this guide when centering things. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of `margin: 0 auto` behavior, `margin: 0 auto` will center the element within it's parent. As Your Features and Share are wider than the rest, they are expanding the parent container, and the rest of your (block elements) sections are aligned left normally. The code you posted works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An inline-block covers the whole line (from left to right), so a margin left and/or right won't work here. What you need is a block, a block has borders on the left and the right so can be influenced by margins. Example

```
#stuff {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You could just use this for the same effect.

```
#stuff {
     text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, these sections *are* centered, you just don't see it in the fiddle since these sections are 940px wide (and the part of the fiddle window is less than that, which is why they are aligned left automatically, to enable access to the whole container). You see it here, the codepen is wider than 940px ( on a full size desktop monitor):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXQZBA

In case you want the *text* in these sections centered, add `text-align: center;` to their CSS rules. I did that in the above codepen.